# Сравнение строк equals выдает false

Tags: android, equals

Есть код:

```
public class AlarmTimer extends BroadcastReceiver implements Constants{

    NotificationManager nm;
    SharedPreferences sp;
    Context ct;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ct=context;
        nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        sp = context.getSharedPreferences(CHECK_SETTINGS,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        push();
    }
    public void push() {
        try {
            new asynchronousGet().run();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("Eror","errorororor");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void pushText(String str1,String str2){

        Intent intent=new Intent(ct,WebActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(KEY_INTENT,str2);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(ct,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(ct);

        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ico)
                .setContentTitle("Hodite")
                .setContentText(str1); // Текст уведомления

        Notification notification = builder.build();
        notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND |
                Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        // ставим флаг, чтобы уведомление пропало после нажатия
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        nm.notify((str1+str2).hashCode(),notification);
    }


    /*---------------------КЛАСС ДЛЯ СЧИТЫВАНИЕ ТЕКСТА ИЗ ФАЙЛА-----------*/
    public class asynchronousGet {
        private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        public void run() throws Exception {
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(URL_TEXT_TXT)
                    .build();

            client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                    try (ResponseBody responseBody = response.body()) {
                        if (!response.isSuccessful())
                            throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

                        Headers responseHeaders = response.headers();
                        for (int i = 0, size = responseHeaders.size(); i < size; i++) {
                            System.out.println(responseHeaders.name(i) + ": " + responseHeaders.value(i));
                        }
                        // Log.i("Good",responseBody.string());
                        // System.out.print(responseBody.string().toString());//СЧИТАННЫЙ ТЕКСТ
                        String string=responseBody.string();
                        int count=0;
                        String[] strings=new String[2];


                        for (String str : string.split("\n")) {
                            Log.i("str",str);
                            strings[count]=str;
                            count++;
                        }


                        String s1; //Текст считанный с файла в телефоне (Текст)
                        String s2; //Текст считанный с файла в телефоне (Ссылка)

                        s1=sp.getString(notif_text, "notif_text");
                        Log.i("s1",s1);
                        s2=sp.getString(notif_url, "notif_url");
                        Log.i("s2",s2);

                        if(!(s1.equalsIgnoreCase(strings[0]) && s2.equalsIgnoreCase(strings[1]))){
                            Log.i(TAG_MYSERVICE,"Сравниваемые строки 1: " + String.valueOf(s1.equals(strings[0])));
                            Log.i(TAG_MYSERVICE,"Сравниваемые строки 2: " +String.valueOf(s2.equals(strings[1])));
                            Log.i(TAG_MYSERVICE,s1+" : "+strings[0]);
                            Log.i(TAG_MYSERVICE,s2+" : "+strings[1]);

                            Log.i(TAG_MYSERVICE,String.valueOf(s1.length())+":"+String.valueOf(strings[0].length()));
                            Log.i(TAG_MYSERVICE,String.valueOf(s2.length())+":"+String.valueOf(strings[1].length()));
                                /*Отправляем строки в уведомление*/
                            pushText(strings[0],strings[1]);

                                /*Сохранение переменных в SharedPreference*/
                            SharedPreferences.Editor e = sp.edit();
                            e.putString(notif_text, strings[0]);
                            e.putString(notif_url, strings[1]);
                            e.commit(); // не забудьте подтвердить изменения
                        }

                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

Фото с логами:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В данном коде есть массив из двух строк, в нём хранится текст, и две строки, которые считывают данные из файла в памяти телефона.

Если строки разные, то выполняется метод pushText и пересохраняются строки.
Таким образом я проверяю изменился ли текст или нет.

Но проблема в том, что моё условие часто срабатывает ложно, хотя строки все одинаковы. В чём проблема? Я не правильно сравниваю строки или что ещё может быть?

Кодировка файла, с которого я считываю текст UTF-8.

Update: добавил весь код

Вот так я изменяю сохраняю текстовый файл:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы пробовали заместо && использовать &? Посмотрите здесь http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/comparison.php об операторах сравнения.

Comment: Строки сравниваются правильно. Проблема явно в чем то другом. Может когда считываете из файла, что-то лишнее цепляется, какие-то управляющие символы и т.д. Может дело в кодировке

Comment: @Иван не помогло. Добавил код

Comment: @Likhanov да,я считываю текстовый документ с сервера.

Comment: @Likhanov добавил полный код в вопрос

Comment: @Likhanov знаю,что кодировка добавлялась,ибо по началу русские символы не считывало

Comment: @Иван кодировка файла UTF-8

Comment: @Likhanov кодировка файла UTF-8